# Query to check if trigger exist on a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Is there a query which lists all the triggers created for any event on a particular table.

Say I have a table named `client`, and I want to list all the triggers creared for any event(say insert/update/delete etc) on that table.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[SHOW TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-triggers.html)

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE '<tablename>'
```

e.g.

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'client'
```

Comment: Is it mandatory that the table name should be there in the trigger's name?

Comment: No it isn't, as far as you're concerned... this is handled internally within MySQL.... the example on the manual page I've linked has a totally doifferent trigger name (ins_sum) to the table name (account)

Comment: +1 and an acceptance, I understand that this question is too basic, but I didnt have any idea about the triggers...
thanks once again..:-)

Comment: One thing to make sure (it was really frustrating for me) is that you are running with sufficient privileges. I was running with a user with minimal privileges only on the schema I was interested in and was flustered that it seemed like the schema has no triggers whatsoever. Running the same query as root and suddenly all my triggers were visible again!

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is correct and the most straightforward method, but for an enhanced view of the triggers on a table and more control over what is returned, use INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS where EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='client';`

With this, you can filter on things like `EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE` (table name), `TRIGGER_SCHEMA`, `EVENT_MANIPULATION` (insert, update, delete, etc), and a slew of other attributes.

As pointed out in the comments above, you'll need to have TRIGGER permissions for this method as well.